# VBA: Running Code on Selected Excel Tab and Consecutively on All Tabs to the Right

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up a VBA macro that is running a VBA operation consecutively in each spreadsheet of a given Excel file. Given that there are numerous sheets in the file, which leads to occasional interruptions with the server, I have to restart the request every once in a while.

So here comes the question: I am looking to modify the code element below in a way that the VBA macro starts running on the currently selected sheet/tab. It shall then consecutively cover all remaining sheets/tabs to the right of the active sheet, but not those to the left which have already been populated.

The code below restarts the each run of the macro with the very first sheet/tab of the file, which is not necessary. Is there any smart tweak to the code?

```
  Dim xsheet As Worksheet
  For Each xsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  xsheet.Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Continue Through Worksheets

If you want to continue with the `ActiveSheet`, just remove ' + 1'.

**Warning**: These codes are valid if you **only** have **worksheets** in the workbook, and not charts, dialogs or whatever.
I almost always use only worksheets in my workbooks so I never learned about the **Index** issue that [JohnyL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3187033/johnyl) is referring to in [his answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266798/vba-running-code-on-selected-excel-tab-and-consecutively-on-all-tabs-to-the-rig/54274904#54274904).

### The Idea

```
Sub ContinueThroughWorksheets()
    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook
        For i = .ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To .Worksheets.Count
            Debug.Print .Worksheets(i).Name
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

### The Implementation

```
Sub ContinueThroughWorksheets2()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    With ThisWorkbook
       Select Case .ActiveSheet.Index
           Case 1
               j = 1
           Case .Worksheets.Count
               Exit Sub
           Case Else
               j = .ActiveSheet.Index + 1
       End Select
       For i = j To .Worksheets.Count
          Debug.Print .Worksheets(i).Name
       Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Never rely on `Index` property

Comment: @JohnyL: When I use 'For each ws in .Worksheets', is it guaranteed that it will loop in the exact order from '1 To .Worksheets.Count' ?. i.e. would reading it in this way into an array and then looping through its elements make a difference?

Comment: There are three sheets-specific collections: `Worksheets`, `Charts` and `DialogSheets`. The `Index` property of these collections returns `Sheet`'s collection index - not the actual index in specific collection. Say, you have four sheets: 1) worksheet ("Sheet1"), 2) worksheet ("Sheet2"), 3) chart ("Chart1")
 and 4) worksheet ("Sheet3"). In this case `Worksheets("Sheet3")` returns `4` when the *real* index is `3`.

Comment: @JohnyL: Can't believe it. Have to check for myself and will get back to you.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @JohnyL: I always thought that Sheets had one list of indexes, Worksheets another, Charts another etc. Turns out there is only one list of indexes, namely the Sheets' indexes and the other indexes are only a 'subset' of it. Thanks for teaching me this lesson.

Answer (score 2):

There are three sheet-specific collections: `Worksheets`, `Charts` and `DialogSheets`. The `Index` property of these collections returns `Sheets`'s collection index - not the actual index in sheet-specific collection.

Say, you have four sheets:

1. Worksheet ("Sheet1")
2. Worksheet ("Sheet2")
3. Chart ("Chart1")
4. Worksheet ("Sheet3").

In this case `Worksheets("Sheet3").Index` returns `4` when the real index is `3`. The bottom line is never rely on `Index` property of sheet-specific collection when it comes to processing all the sheets.

To solve you problem you just need to use `Sheets` collection:

```
Sub FFF()
    Dim x%, sheet As Variant
    For x = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Sheets.Count
        Set sheet = Sheets(x)
        '// Do something with sheet
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, the code is working well for the currently activated sheet. However, it does not seem to move to the other sheets following completion....

Answer (score 1):

You can do it thus, but note that it's generally not advisable to base code on the active sheet or active cells as they can easily be changed and your code may not run correctly.

A better method would be to store the (code)names of the sheets processed elsewhere and loop through your sheets excluding those names.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long

For i = ActiveSheet.Index To Worksheets.Count
    MsgBox Worksheets(i).Name
Next i

End Sub
```